# Error when installing ExtendedSelenium2library

Tags: selenium, robotframework

> C:\Users\Sachini>pip install robotframework-extendedselenium2library
> Collecting robotframework-extendedselenium2library
> Using cached robotframework-extendedselenium2library-0.9.2.tar.gz (107 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
> Collecting selenium>=2.46.1
> Using cached selenium-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.3 MB)
> Collecting robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
> Using cached robotframework-selenium2library-1.8.0.tar.gz (118 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> [32 lines of output]
> Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File

Comment: Can you try "pip install --upgrade setuptools"

Comment: I am getting this when I typed
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\sachini\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (65.7.0)